# Check to see if the primary key exists in other multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a `t1` table and its id is used in other tables (`t2`, `t3`, `t4`). I want to check if the `t1` `id` exists in any of  other tables. how can i do that.

```
t1: modelpapers
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | level_FK  |   cdate    |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         1 | 2019-12-26 |
|  8 |         3 | 2019-12-20 |
|  2 |         2 | 2019-12-22 |
|  6 |         4 | 2019-12-24 |
+----+-----------+------------+

t2: lvl_addition
+----+----------------+------+------+-----+
| id | modelpaper_FK  | num1 | num2 | ... |
+----+----------------+------+------+-----+
|  1 |              8 |  235 |   42 |     |
|  2 |              6 |   52 |    3 |     |
+----+----------------+------+------+-----+
NOTE: modelpaper_FK is the PK of the modelpapers table

t3: lvl_multiplication
+----+----------------+------+------+-----+
| id | modelpaper_FK  | num1 | num2 | ... |
+----+----------------+------+------+-----+
|  1 |              8 |  235 |   42 |     |
|  2 |              1 |   52 |    3 |     |
+----+----------------+------+------+-----+
NOTE: modelpaper_FK is the PK of the modelpapers table

t4: lvl_divisions
NOTE: similar to the tables from above.
```

This is the query iam outputting it currently without checking the id's from other three tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, cdate FROM modelpapers WHERE level_FK = ".$queryStringIdFromURL;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

How can i use this query to check if the modelpaper `id` exists in other three tables

#### Output

```
You are in Level 2 - Addition of the Modelsheet page.
+=======+============+=======+
| level | Arithmetic | notes |
+=======+============+=======+
|     2 | Addition   |     - |
+-------+------------+-------+

[Generate Model paper]
You can generate only n number of papers. 
Once you reached the limit, the [Generate Model paper] button will be disabled.

+===============+=========================================+=========+
|  model paper  |             Generate paper              | status  |
+===============+=========================================+=========+
| Model paper 1 | [Generate paper]                        | -       |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+
| Model paper 2 | Your paper is generated on 23 nov 2019  | Success |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+
| Model paper 3 | [Generate paper]                        | -       |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+
```

When the user click the `[Generate paper]` button it will import a set of numbers from Excel sheet to database (this is working as expected). Everytime the database INSERT iam adding the modelpaper `id` to it. So i can check how many times the excel is inserted into the database.

Now i need to check if the modelpaper `id` exists in the other tables. There are three tables (lvl_addition, lvl_multiplication, and lvl_division). As you can see from teh above table, the user is in level 2 - addition so the table will be lvl_addition. Instead of checking in all three table, i can also check if the id exists on the lvl_addition table alone.

I am not sure it make any sense but let me know if you have any doubt.

Here's the while loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $modelpaperId = $row['id'];
    echo "<a href='excel_add.php'>Generate Paper</a>";
}
```

Comment: What result do you want to get if it exists, or if it doesn't?

Comment: column name would be preferable. I am using a loop to output the `modelpaper` table, so if the id exists i can able to get the column names and output it.

Comment: @Dexter which column names, the `modelpaper` or other tables column names?

Comment: If you could provide the expected output for e.g. `level_FK = 3` (or 1 or 4) that would be helpful in terms of answering the question.

Comment: You need a simple join in this case.

Comment: @Nick i have included the desired output.

Comment: Unfortunately question is closed so I can't answer but you basically need a `LEFT JOIN` to all 3 tables and just check whether the `modelpaper_FK` field is `NULL` or not in each table to determine whether that table's paper has been generated or not.